POST to Restful API
I am creating A Restful API (Using Visual Basic/C#).
I have a Class/Model with a single field:
public class ResultsiMeter
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
}


My Controller:
[Route("api/[controller]")]

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] ResultsiMeter resultsiMeter)
{
    return;
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

My get request actually hits the spot
GET http://localhost:63719/Api/iMeterResults HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:63719
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.2)

and returns the 2 values
When I Fire off a POST request
POST http://localhost:63719/Api/iMeterResults HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 19
Host: localhost:63719
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.2)

{
"id": 12345
}

I receive a 400 response which appears to suggest a structure issue ??
application/problem+json; charset=utf-8, 185 bytes
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-7bf623aeedb0abf41a13dd0a5e87a045-48a6258679cea4d5-00"
}

I cannot for the life of me see what is wrong.
The JSON is very simple and appears to be constructed correctly.
Can anyone put a newbie numpty on the right path as I am flumoxed?

try changing the return type from void to some object and sending back something as response from the controller.

Good morning.
Thank you for the suggestion.
I changed the post to
public string Post([FromBody] ResultsiMeter resultsiMeter)
{
    return "Got Here";
}

But I still get the same response.
I have a break point at
return "Got Here";
but It does not get there.
It looks like the request is not getting there at all

I came across a comment elsewhere whilst searching for a solution and they suggested (for their solution) that the attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] should be added to the Post.
Hey ho. This does the trick.
I am not sure why but I will dig into that now.
Thank you all for reading my post and for the help offered

It was en error on my part. A simple incorrect spelling on a field name did it.
Thank you for all the advice offered

It it's a minor issue regarding a type, you might want to consider to close the question.

Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review
